# Unreal Engine 4 default sphere mesh location

Tags: unreal-engine4

Where can I find the base mesh and uv map of the default sphere used in the material editor for previewing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the option to show the Engine content under View Options in the Editor content browser. A folder Engine Content will appear where you can search for Sphere under BasicShapes.

Comment: Alternately you can double click on the material the default sphere is using, this will open it up and allow you to view the blueprint logic (UV options)